# Business Objects Webi error IES 10811 with custom SQL

Tags: business-objects

We are working with WEBIs that have been released from a Universe modified from the standard Epic released universe and have to make a few small changes to the SQL code behind the WEBIs

The fields joined are still the same data type and none of the fields in the SELECT or WHERE clause have changed, but for some reason we get this error code when we press the Validate button 'The data type of a column in the query is not valid. (IES 10811)'

Anyone have advice on what else I can troubleshoot? Thanks in advance!

**Modified Code aliases X_CLARITY_SER using a table with the exact same data structure called CLARITY_SER_2**

> INNER JOIN **CLARITY_SER_2 X_CLARITY_SER_800** ON >(V_LOG_BASED.PRIMARY_PHYSICIAN_ID=X_CLARITY_SER_800.PROV_ID)
>   **LEFT OUTER JOIN** ZC_PAT_SERVICE ON (X_CLARITY_SER_800.SERVICE_DEFAULT_C=ZC_PAT_SERVICE.HOSP_SERV_C)

**Original Code**

> INNER JOIN X_CLARITY_SER_800 ON (V_LOG_BASED.PRIMARY_PHYSICIAN_ID=X_CLARITY_SER_800.PROV_ID)
>   INNER JOIN ZC_PAT_SERVICE ON (X_CLARITY_SER_800.SERVICE_DEFAULT_C=ZC_PAT_SERVICE.HOSP_SERV_C)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the solution was to refresh the source tables in the Universe Designer.
BO chose types of columns with a date in a wrong way (as character columns) and that's why columns types of my new table didn't match.

EDIT:
I met with such problem as mapping `varchar` columns in a database vs. `date` columns in BO also with an error `"Unexpected behavior" (IES 10901) (FBE60502)` when I wanted to send emails with BO publication.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that the datatype of one of the universe objects doesn't match the datatype of the database column.  That *shouldn't* happen in your case, in which you're changing to another table with the same structure.  I'm wondering if maybe one of of the objects in the universe has an incorrect datatype -- that is, the problem is present regardless of your SQL change, but it is just noticing the problem when it tries to parse the SQL.

I would do an integrity check in the universe.  That will identify any incorrect datatypes.  I'm assuming you've double-checked that two tables really do have an identical structure, but might be worth checking again.

Finally, as a brute-force method of debugging, I would just start removing objects from the query (and the associated column in the SQL) to find the one causing the problem.